# Pushing a struct that contains an array into a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I am writing a program that performs differential evolution. At one point I am sorting my solutions into an archive of solutions and have run into this problem. My archive is a vector of structs:

```
std::vector<SingleSolution> archive;

typedef struct SingleSolution
{
    int *crop_area;
    int *envf;
    double nr_cost;
    int env_cost;
    int front;
    int feasible;
} SingleSolution;
```

When I am doing the sort and have a solution I want to put into my archive, I am creating a SingleSolution and pushing it to the archive:

```
SingleSolution member;
member.crop_area = (int *)calloc(crops + 1, sizeof(int));
member.envf = (int *)calloc(M + 1, sizeof(int));
member.front = 1;
member.feasible = feasible[member1];
member.nr_cost = nr_costs[member1];
member.env_cost = env_costs[member1];
for (int n = 1; n <= crops; n++) member.crop_area[n] = solution_crop[member1][n];
for (int n = 1; n <= M; n++) member.envf[n] = solution_env[member1][n];

archive.push_back(member);
//free(member.crop_area);
//free(member.envf);
```

I was freeing those arrays after pushing to the vector, as I thought that it made a copy of what I was pushing in, but in printing the archive I saw what were obviously junk values and realised why. So as you can see I have commented it out.
So my question is, what exactly is happening in that push_back? It it pushing the location in memory where the arrays start, and then I am freeing that space? Any way that I can overcome this, or do I need to be creating the space in the main function and pass it through when I call the sort function, then free it at completion?

Comment: If you're using c++ there's no need to deal with raw pointers yourself. In fact it's actually discouraged a lot, and you should immediately stop that!

Comment: A copy of a pointer, is another pointer pointing to the same location. You should make `crop_area` and `envf` be vectors

Comment: You already know how to use `std::vector` to store your `SingleSolution` instances. It is a perfect fit for storing the `crop_area` and `envf` information as well. Don't make things hard for yourself.

Comment: I realize this is pedantic, but the struct you have made does not contain an array, it contains pointers. Containing an array would be like `int foo[30];`. Please correct the question title. In addition the way you would make this work in idiomatic C++ is to define a destructor and copy constructor for your struct (and perhaps assignment ops and move constructors etc) (or use a container like vector to handle it all for you)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
archive.push_back(member);
```

You ask it to *copy* `member` to the end of the `archive` vector using a copy constructor. You can say "there is no copy constructor in `SingleSolution`", but actually there is - the one provided by the compiler which makes **shallow** copies of the struct members. This is where your problem resides. You are using raw pointers, and the default copy constructor is only copying the *values* of the pointers (the memory addresses where they are pointing at - your buffers).

This is a great way to cause undefined behaviour or memory leaks when you try to manage these resources yourself. You realized that when you freed the buffers but still had pointers that were pointing at the old memory.

Let's try to rewrite this piece of code in C++.

First, you don't need that `typedef`.

Second, your buffers can be replaced with `std::vector`:

```
struct SingleSolution
{
    std::vector<int> crop_area;
    std::vector<int> envf;
    double nr_cost;
    int env_cost;
    int front;
    int feasible;
};
```

To fill your structure, without worrying about memory allocation/deallocation, you can do this:

```
SingleSolution member;

member.crop_area.resize(crops+1);
member.crop_area[0] = 0;
std::copy(&solution_crop[member1][1], &solution_crop[member1][crops+1], member.crop_area.begin()+1);

member.envf.resize(M+1);
member.envf[0] = 0;
std::copy(&solution_env[member1][1], &solution_env[member1][M+1], member.envf.begin()+1);

member.front = 1;
member.feasible = feasible[member1];
member.nr_cost = nr_costs[member1];
member.env_cost = env_costs[member1];

archive.push_back(member);
```

Or this:

```
SingleSolution member;

member.crop_area.reserve(crops+1);
member.crop_area.push_back(0);
std::copy(&solution_crop[member1][1], &solution_crop[member1][crops+1], std::back_inserter(member.crop_area));
// or: std::copy_n(&solution_crop[member1][1], crops, std::back_inserter(member.crop_area));

member.envf.reserve(M+1);
member.envf.push_back(0);
std::copy(&solution_env[member1][1], &solution_env[member1][M+1], std::back_inserter(member.envf));
// or: std::copy_n(&solution_env[member1][1], M, std::back_inserter(member.envf));

member.front = 1;
member.feasible = feasible[member1];
member.nr_cost = nr_costs[member1];
member.env_cost = env_costs[member1];

archive.push_back(member);
```

Comment: your `copy` writes out of bounds

Comment: @M.M really? I thought `&solution_crop[member1][crop]` would be equivalent at `.end()` member function.  And, the way OP initialize its operands seems to me to be awkward. So, I correct it to 0 until crop - 1. Or I really do not understood your comment

Comment: Yes, it is more natural to use 0-based indexing, and that is what `vector` uses. But the OP's code is using 1-based indexing instead. I tweaked your example to make it compatible with 1-based logic, so it doesn't break the rest of the user's code that uses the `crop`/`envf` data. Besides, you weren't allocating the `vector`s before `copy()`'ing into them anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks

Comment: @Amadeus `copy` writes into space that is already allocated, you were writing into empty vectors

Comment: @M.M got it. thanks

Comment: Thank you all, you are quite right about the odd indexing. I am in a position where I was required to start from some already implemented code and it was like that throughout as they wanted to refer to things like months 1-12 etc. It has been a bit of a pain though!
This has certainly all got me headed in the right direction, just some other functions around the place to change accordingly etc but I think this will all come together. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`push_back()` adds a *copy* of the `SingleSolution` struct to the end of the vector.

Now, that struct happens to contain some pointers. That's nice, but `push_back()` doesn't care. It has no specific knowledge of what those pointers are pointing to. They could be pointing to some static buffers. They could be pointing to dynamically-allocated buffers (which would be your case), or they could be completely uninitialized pointers.

Whatever the case may be, `push_back()` doesn't care. Its job is to copy the given struct to the end of the vector, and that's what it does.  It makes a copy of whatever is in the struct, it does not allocate anything new within the copy.

If you dynamically allocate some buffers, and set the pointers in the struct to point to those buffers, and then add a copy of the struct to the vector, and then you free those buffers, the pointers in the struct in the vector will be pointing to freed buffers, the pointers will no longer be valid.

So, don't free the original buffers while any instance of the struct is still pointing at those buffers.  Free them only after you have cleared the `vector`.  Or, you can add a copy constructor to the struct to allocate its own copies of the memory buffers, and add a destructor to free those copied buffers, then you can free the original buffers whenever you want.